# Init array with range of Int-s, can someone explain this one-liner?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I'd like to initialise an array of Int-s with a series of numbers. Example [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]. I know there are some better way than using the for loop and I've fond this one-liner that works `var values: [Int] = (0...4).map() { $0 }`. But I just can't understand what's going on here. I understand I have a range 0...4. Is this range in brackets behaving like closure? And what does the map() function do? I can't find it in the reference. And also $0 is something I can't understand. Can someone explain what's going on here?

```
var values: [Int] = (0...4).map() { $0 }
// result: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

.I'm still using Swift 1.2

Comment: I cannot test it currently, but you should get the same result with the simpler `var values = Array(0 ... 4)`.

Comment: Yes Martin, I can confirm it is working. And it's very human readable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(0...4)
```

creates a `Range`

```
.map() { $0 }
```

applies a transformation (which here is no transformation)to each element of that range and returns an array containing the results of that transformation, which is a `[Int]`. The reference for [map](http://swiftdoc.org/type/Range/), at the bottom.
And the `$0` means the first parameter of the method, so `$1` would be the second parameter and so on. And here `$0` means first 0, then 1...

And for example if you want to create 2, 4, 6, you could use map like this:

```
var values = (1...3).map { $0 * 2 }
```

so you multiply first 1 * 2, then 2 * 2 finally 3 * 2.

Answer (score 1):

The brackets surrounding the range are only used to use methods of the Range type, in this case `map`.
This method takes each elements of your collection (a range in your code), pass it to a closure or block (`{ $0 }`) and the return value of the closure is used in the collection returned by `map`.
Swift syntax allow to write closure after the brackets of `map()`, if the closure is very simple you can even omit `return` and parameters name which will be called `$x` where `x` is a zero-based progressive number, in your case `$0` represents the number of your range.

If we expand your code to make it more clear we get

```
let range = 0...4
bar values: [Int] = range.map({ (i: Int) -> Int in
    return i
})
```